# Apache Spark Connector Driver not suitable

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark, pyspark

Trying to connect to sqlserver using Azure Apache Spark connector and getting the following error

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver

Databricks cluster has com.microsoft.azure:spark-mssql-connector_2.12:1.2.0 for Apache Spark 3.1.2, Scala 2.12 as stated my [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/spark/connector?view=sql-server-ver15)

That's the only library I have installed on the cluster.

Went through docs on
https://github.com/microsoft/sql-spark-connector

```
jdbcHostname = "server name"
jdbcPort = 1433
jdbcDatabase = "database name"
Table="tbl.name"
JDBC_URL='"jdbc:sqlserver://{0}:{1};database={2}"'.format(jdbcHostname,jdbcPort,jdbcDatabase)
username="user"
password="pass"

jdbcDF = spark.read \
         .format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark") \
         .option("url", JDBC_URL) \
         .option("dbtable", Table) \
         .option("user", username) \
         .option("password", password).load()
```

Comment: You need to use `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver` driver instead. [See this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/sql-databases)

Comment: @DKNY thats for standard JDBC connection driver. Am using the spark connector as it has much faster write times then standard JDBC https://github.com/microsoft/sql-spark-connector

Comment: But aren't you reading data here?

Comment: @MuhammadPathan, were you able to find a solution for this problem? If yes could you please share it here as I'm too facing similar issue. See my comment below.

Comment: @saravanair yeah managed to find the solution to the problem after lots of  digging.  It was a driver issue for me. I changed to this driver com.microsoft.azure:spark-mssql-connector_2.12_3.0:1.0.0-alpha and it worked